# Could anyone of you please let me know, In shell Scripting if Input =Prefixname_SuffixName-123, how to get only the part after '_' as new Input?

Tags: linux, powershell, shell, unix, scripting

Could anyone of you please let me know, In **shell Scripting** if Input =Prefixname_SuffixName-123, how to get only the part after '_' as new Input ?

Input = Prefixname_SuffixName-123

Expected should be,
New_input = SuffixName-123

Note: The prefixname is not fixed length string, it varies all the time.

I have tried,

new_name=cat $input | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d="_"

error :
cut: expected a list of bytes, characters, or fields

Comment: Why is this question tagged "powershell"?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible test case, which can be copied and pasted; and, please, format the code in your question according to the stackoverflow [formatting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also I don't understand why it is is tagged _powershell_, and why you tag it as _unix_ **and** _linux_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
new_name=$(echo "$Input" | awk -F_ '{print $2}')
```

and if you were using `bash` instead of `sh` you could do

```
Input='Prefixname_SuffixName-123'
new_name=${Input#*_}
echo "$new_name"
SuffixName-123
```